# Measurements taken in Euler's equation of rigid body motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am having some confusion about the frames involved in Euler's equation of rotational motion. 
$$
\mathbf{I} \dot{\boldsymbol\omega} + \boldsymbol\omega \times \left( \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol\omega \right) = \mathbf{M}.
$$
All of the quantity above are measured in the rotating body frame.

Now, here is my confusion: if one observes the body in the body frame (comoving with the body), then the body is stationary. This means that $\omega=0$ for this observer. So this cannot be the value of $\omega$ in the equation.

So, what is the $\omega$ in the equation? I think it is the angular velocity observed in the inertial frame BUT expressed as a combination of basis vectors of the rotating frame.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity vector ,where the components of $\vec{\omega}$ are given in  body fixed frame

Comment: @Eli So, omega is the same as the one in inertial frame except that it is expressed in a different basis？

Comment: That is correct, your equations are also valid in inertial frame

Comment: @Eli Also in inertial frame? That's difficult to imagine. The dot on omega is taken in rotating frame...

Comment: dot omega is $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{\omega}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \dot {\omega}_{{x}}\\ \dot{\omega}_{{y}
}\\ \dot{\omega}_{{z}}\end {array} \right] $, in any  frame. so if the components of omega is given in body fixed frame the equation is still valid.

Comment: @Eli But isn't time derivative in a rotating frame different from the time derivative in the inertial frame? That gives rise to the $\omega\times (I\omega)$ term.